# Archive a specific item in Exchange Server 2010

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I developed an automated procedure (.Net code) running in a Windows service and scheduled by a custom scheduler using timers. This procedure uses EWS to read emails and load attachments.

After successfully processing an email, I would like to move it to the archive inbox (like you can do in Outlook). I searched quite a bit for the correct way to move an item to the archives, but the only straightforward way I found is to use the `ArchiveItem` operation, which is only available from [Exchange Server 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/jj219964%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx). After inspecting the API, I found two other possible ways to do it, but didn't find any reliable example of usage and I'm not even sure they would apply to my situation :

- [Item.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634928%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)
- [ExchangeService.ArchiveItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.archiveitems%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

Did someone have something similar to accomplish, and how did you do it?

Comment: A good answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685782/c-sharp-ms-exchange-move-email-to-folder 

Hope it helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom folder with the name "processed items", then moving each processed item to this folder by using `Item.Move`.

I didn't find a way to directly archive an item.